# Empty Spring Model Attributes in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following block of javascript code, and a variable called 'total_calls_p' passed in the model from spring to my jsp page.

```js
var c = 0;
if (${! empty total_calls_p})
    c = ${total_calls_p};
```

When the page first loads, the total_calls_p variable is not in the model, thus it is empty. I have tried to account for this with the if statement above. However, even with the if statement, the javascript errors out because the code looks like this:

```js
var c = 0;
if (false)
    c = ;
```

This causes an error:

```java
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Is there a way to have jquery put a default value if the attribute is empty? Perhaps something like this:

```js
${total_calls_p default 0}
```

Comment: Why all the hacking around? Isn't it much simpler to let the controller add a default value to the model? You should not do this kind of logic inside your view.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
<c:set var="jsTotal" value="${empty total_calls_p ? total_calls_p : '0'}" />
c = ${jsTotal};
```

Of course in the jsp you would need to have

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

in the jsp.

Or of course you could just make the change in the controller and just have the model simply set the value to a javascript variable

Answer (score 0):

Use JSTL Core tag library to check for a value before putting it in the output. If the condition passes, then the HTML (javascript in this case) will be rendered to output. If the expression is not satisfied, it will not be rendered:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:if test="${not empty total_calls_p}">
    c = ${total_calls_p};
</c:if>
```

Is there any reason why you can't just put the value 0 in your spring model to begin with? Then you wouldn't have to do this logic in the view, which is what spring tries to promote (i.e. keeping logic out of view).